# How to parse RSS link (get ulr to RSS) from the page in Python framework Scrapy?

Tags: python, xpath, rss, parsing, scrapy

I want to parse Google search and get links to RSS from each item from the search results.
I use Scrapy. 
I tried this construction,

```
...
def parse_second(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    qqq = hxs.select('/html/head/link[@type=application/rss+xml]/@href').extract()
    print qqq
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    if len(qqq) > 0:
        item['rss'] = qqq.pop()
    else:
        item['rss'] = ''    
    yield item
...
```

but
"print qqq" gives me

```
[]
```

Comment: Could you include a sample of the HTML you are trying to match against?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a mistake:

```
qqq = hxs.select("/html/head/link[@type='application/rss+xml']/@href").extract()
```

that works